# Imagenes dentro de un if en PHP

Tags: php, imagen, condiciones

siempre miro el foro para sacarme dudas y normalmente me resulta de mucha utilidad, en esta ocasión no fue el caso. Estoy incursionando en el lenguaje PHP y estaba intentando armar una tirada de dados en una pagina, a futuro la idea es armar tiradas de dados de diferentes cantidades de caras para jugar D&D. Quería usar un "rand(1,6)" dándole valor a una variable "$num" y que en base al numero random que salga que muestre una imagen del dado con la cara correspondiente. Ahi comienza el problema, viendo algunos post logré visualizar todas las imagenes con un while, pero al momento de querer mostrar las imágenes en un if no encontré ninguna forma que funcione. Dejo el código abajo para que me puedan decir en que me estoy equivocando:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tirada de dados</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$num = rand(1,6);
if ($num == 1) {
    $comp= '<img src="c:/xampp/htdocs/dados/1.jpg">';
    echo $comp;
} elseif ($num == 2) {
    $comp= '<img src="c:/xampp/htdocs/dados/2.jpg">';
    echo $comp;
} elseif ($num == 3) {
    $comp= '<img src="c:/xampp/htdocs/dados/3.jpg">';
    echo $comp;
} elseif ($num == 4) {
    $comp= '<img src="c:/xampp/htdocs/dados/4.jpg">';
    echo $comp;
} elseif ($num == 5) {
    $comp= '<img src="c:/xampp/htdocs/dados/5.jpg">';
    echo $comp;
} else ($num == 6) {
    $comp= '<img src="c:/xampp/htdocs/dados/6.jpg">';
    echo $comp;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Intenté mostrando las imagenes en html cerrando con ?> antes de cada imágen y abriendo con <? antes de cada elseif y no funcionó. También intente mostrar las imágenes sin el $comp pero no tuve suerte tampoco, esto es lo mejor que pude armar por el momento. Las imágenes estan en una carpeta nombrada "dados" dentro de la carpeta htdocs en el directorio del Xampp que es la app que uso.

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo para leer este post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que hacer comparaciones, simplemente colocar el número en la ruta de la imagen.

Las imágenes no se muestran porque estás usando ruta de disco y no URL, creo que todos los navegadores bloquean el acceso por motivos de seguridad.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tirada de dados</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$num = rand(1,6);
// Ya tienes el número, solo muestra la imagen, sin comparaciones
echo "<img src=\"dados/$num.jpg\">";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Super rápida la respuesta y funciona a la perfección! no se me ocurrió hacerlo de esa manera, muy eficiente!